# Shortcode for AdSense banners in Blogger

Tags: blogger, shortcode

I find this code, i have tried this on blogger but this isnt work for me..
Is it possible to make it work?

this is the code:

```
function adsense_func( $atts ){
 $ad = '

//You can change the code between the <script> tags with your personal Ad code
 <script type="text/javascript"><!--
 google_ad_client = "Adsense ID";
 google_ad_width = 336;
 google_ad_height = 280;
 google_ad_format = "336x280_as";
 google_ad_type = "text";
 google_ad_channel = "";
 google_color_border = "ffffff";
 google_color_bg = "FFFFFF";
 google_color_link = "0000FF";
 google_color_text = "000000";
 google_color_url = "11593C";
 //-->
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>

//Finish editing
 ';

 return $ad;
}
add_shortcode( 'adsense', 'adsense_func' );
```

I want to make Shortcode on Blogger for my Adsense to make easy make changes
Can you please help me with that?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this is a PHP code created specifically for WordPress and therefore will not work on Blogger.

Additionally a format of your code is slightly different as per [official Google guidelines](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/181950?hl=en).

Structure of your Blogger blog template is similar, either find a opening `<blog>` tag, or place the code in empty `HTML/JavaScript` widget created from your blog dashboard.

Although I'm pretty sure that AdSense code should already be inserted in your template by default, here's a sample code (you will receive similar one by creating your own **ad code**):

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Homepage Leaderboard -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234567890123456"
data-ad-slot="1234567890"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Thanks,
Luca